# Hanami - How to properly check if a model has been persisted?

Tags: ruby, hanami

I'm a newbie in hanami coming from a rails background, and I would like to know the best practice in verifying that a model has been persisted in a create Action.

I created a users/create action that looks like this:

```
class Create
    include Web::Action

    def call(params)
          repository = UserRepository.new

          @user = repository.create(name: params[:user][:name], 
                                    email: params[:user][:email],
                                    type: 'standard')
          redirect_to '/users'
    end
  end
```

I wanted to make sure that I only redirect the users if the user was successfully created. I rails, I would do something like this:

```
redirect_to '/users' if @user.persisted?
```

But that is not the hanami way of doing things. Currently I'm doing this:

```
redirect_to '/users' if !@user.id.nil?
```

Which does the job, but it doesn't looks clean. How would be the best way to do this with hanami?

Comment: I think, in the way if `user` is not be created by `#create` it raises an error, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
def call(params)
  repository = UserRepository.new

  @user = repository.create(name: params[:user][:name], 
                            email: params[:user][:email],
                            type: 'standard')
  redirect_to '/users'
rescue Hanami::Model::Error
  # handle the error
end
```

Answer (score 2):

ROM/Hanami cannot silently discard the changes you're passing to a repo, it either raises an exception of some kind (`Hanami::Model::Error` in the case of hanami-model) or persists your entity. That said, checks like `@user.id.nil?` are completely redundant.